# HTC 8X as mass storage?

Tags: htc-8x, usb

Is it possible to connect HTC 8X as mass storage.
Current Version: windows 8 phone

I have tried this method to connect as a mass storage
http://www.asoftech.com/articles/windows-phone-enable-mass-storage.html

but it isn't working as after installing zune it isn't detecting the device, driver and everything is correct, as device is being detected by windows and i can browse files in windows explorer under windows phone. (but it is not mass storage).

As this device has only internal storage i am facing it difficult to connect it as mass storage.

Other than this i also tried restarting phone while connected to pc and simultaneously pressing Camera key, which suppose make the connection as mass storage but that is also not working.

Comment: If you're seeing it in the Windows explorer, what exactly are you trying to do / what is the issue? Zune will not recognize the phone as it only works with Windows Phone 7 devices.

Comment: i want it to work as a mass storage, show it as a drive letter so that i can recover some images using recovery software